# Finding the minimal k that 2^k begins with n

Tags: python, algorithm, decimal

Given a positive integer *n* ≤ 10<sup>7</sup>, I need to find the least positive integer *k* such that the decimal representation of 2<sup>*k*</sup> starts with the decimal representation of *n*.

So, for example, if *n* = 12, then *k* = 7 (because 2<sup>7</sup> = **12**8); if *n* = 134, then *k* = 27 (because 2<sup>27</sup> = **134**,217,728); and if *n* = 82, then *k* = 209 (because 2<sup>209</sup> ≈ **8.2**3×10<sup>62</sup>).

(If no such *k* exists, I need to return −1.)

I didn't even attempt to solve it with the formula (I have NO idea how), and decided to solve by calculating all powers of 2 up to 1000, putting them in a list, and then finding the index of the number that begins with n. The code works, but... It doesn't even pass the first test in the system. I have no clue why, because it works correctly for the above examples. Anyway, here is the code.

```
def find_all():
    arr = []
    n = 1
    for i in range(1000):
        arr.append(str(n))
        n = n << 1
    return arr


n = str(n)
NOT_FOUND = True
#n = input()
arr = find_all()
for i in arr:
    if i.startswith(n):
        print(arr.index(i), n)
        NOT_FOUND = False
        break
if NOT_FOUND:
    print(-1, n)
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your code is working for the samples, but assuming you are using some site like hackerrank that tests your code, they are probably using much larger `n` (up to 10,000,000) that don't fit in your "first 1000 numbers" generated.  `k` could be much bigger than 1000.  Is this the complete description of the problem?  Any limits on make 'k'?  How to decide if k doesn't exist (numbers are infinite)?

Comment: The only limit is on n, which is from 1 to 10^7. No limits on k, apparently. No description of how to decide if k exists. Anything other than that is just the setting

Comment: I've found every `n` up to 20,000  and `k` is upwards of 70,000+ so you probably need to adjust your algorithm for bigger numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you want to find a power of 2 that starts with 123.

This is equivalent to finding a multiple of log<sub>10</sub>(2) whose [mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_logarithm#Mantissa_and_characteristic) lies between 0.089905111439398 and 0.093421685162235 (because log<sub>10</sub>(123) = 2.089905111439398 and log<sub>10</sub>(124) = 2.093421685162235).

If you frame the question in this way, there's no need to calculate huge powers of 2. All you need is a bit of floating point arithmetic.

The following code works fairly well, but takes a good few seconds to produce answers when n is close to 10<sup>7</sup>:

```
def power_of_2_with_prefix(n):
    # Find the minimum integer k such that the digits of 2^k
    # start with the digits of n
    from math import log10
    #
    # First deal with trivial cases
    assert type(n) is int
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n < 1:
        return -1
    #
    # Calculate mantissa range
    logmin = log10(n)
    logmax = log10(n+1)
    logmin -= int(logmin)
    logmax -= int(logmax)
    if logmax < logmin:
        logmax += 1
    #
    # Now find a power of 2 whose log10 mantissa lies in this range
    log2 = log10(2)
    # Make sure k is large enough to include all trailing zeros of n
    mink = log10(n) / log10(2)
    x = 1
    k = 0
    while not (logmin <= x < logmax and k >= mink):
        x += log2
        if x >= 1:
            x -= 1
        k += 1
    return k

assert power_of_2_with_prefix(0) == -1
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(1) == 0
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(2) == 1
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(4) == 2
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(40) == 12
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(28584) == 74715
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(28723) == 110057
assert power_of_2_with_prefix(9999999) == 38267831
```